# DarwinPorts or Fink?

Tags: macos

This is an eternal question; however the comments I've found about this date of 2008, and I guess have moved since then.

So, DarwinPorts or Fink? (or something else?)

I see that Fink does not yet have a binary installer for snow leopard...
is it a dead project?

Regards,
David

Comment: http://www.macports.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't be confused by DarwinPorts.com.  The original DarwinPorts project was renamed to [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) a long time ago.

Besides [Fink](https://www.finkproject.org/), yet another distributor of open source packages for OS X has arisen in the mean time: [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).  Each of the three has its strengths depending on your preferences.  None of them currently provide an up-to-date set of binary packages, so whichever you choose, you'll end having to spend time compiling.  In my opinion, `MacPorts` is probably the most actively maintained these days and has at least unofficial support from Apple but `Homebrew` has been gaining in popularity for its minimalist approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Is there a list of applications prepared for Homebrew? I checked the website, but I failed to see such a list.
For instance, this is the list of applications prepared for fink: http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/browse.php

I only found this short list for homebrew: http://wiibrew.org/wiki/List_of_homebrew_applications
but I guess that it is not complete, as mysql does not appear in the list and I know that mysql is prepared for homebrew.

Comment: For Homebrew packages, drill down into the github source for *formula*: http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/tree/master/Library/Formula/